# Different ways to pre-process date in Machine Learning using Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to pre-process the date and use it to train my model in python.
My date format is like this.
**22-02-2026**
 The code I have developed so far is attached below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df['previous_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['previous_date'])
df['current_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['current_date'])

df['previous_date_day'] = df['previous_date'].dt.day
df['previous_date_month'] = df['previous_date'].dt.month
df['previous_date_year'] = df['previous_date'].dt.year

df['current_date_day'] = df['current_date'].dt.day
df['current_date_month'] = df['current_date'].dt.month
df['current_date_year'] = df['current_date'].dt.year



X=df.iloc[:,3:]
Y=df['value']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
acc_score=accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100
print("Accuracy Score : " , acc_score)
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to convert dates to a more amenable format? In that case use [the arrow package](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) and use something like `arrow.get("22-02-2026").timestamp`.

Comment: I just want to compare 2 dates. If the first date is bigger than the second date i want to predict ***true*** else i want my prediction as ***false**. So my question is how should I pre-process the date to train the Machine Learning model.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. Are your dates single string variables or are there inside a pandas Series/Dataframe? Also, it is good practice to show us what you have already tried.

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe contaning 2 columns previous_date and current_date and the third column is the label to be predicted.

Comment: You edited the question after I drafted the answer, so I haven't seen your attempt in pandas. You don't need to split it into day, month and year, in fact it will be cause more harm then good. It's enough if you change replace the date with ordinal number denoting date (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, you need to convert a date to an ordinal number so that the algorithm can tell the order.

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import datetime

origin = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
days = (datetime.datetime.strptime('22-02-2026', '%d-%m-%Y') - origin).days
```

In this case it's `20506`.

I set the origin to Unix epoch, but you can modify it to your likeness. It doesn't really matter, since the purpose here is to tell the order. Majority of machine learning algorithms will be able to use feature in this format, but if it's the best way depends on the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As there are many dates that need to be converted to numeric representation, the first thing to make sure is that the output list also has the same order as Lukas mentioned. The easiest way to do this is by adding weight to each unit (weight_year > weight_month > weight_day).

```
def date2num(date_time):
  d, m, y = date_time.split('-')
  num = int(d)*10 + int(m)*100 + int(y)*1000 # these weights can be anything as long as 
                                             # they are ordered
  return num
```

Now, it's important to normalize the numeric values.

```
import numpy as np
date_features = []
for d in list(df['date_time']):
  date_features.append(date2num(d))
date_features = np.array(date_features)
date_features_normalized = (date_features - np.min(date_features))/(np.max(date_features) - np.min(date_features))
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in one of your comments to your post :

> I just want to compare 2 dates. If the first date is bigger than the
>   second date i want to predict true else i want my prediction as
>   *false. So my question is how should I pre-process the date to train the Machine Learning model.

You do not need machine learning for this, you can solve this only with a if / else condition.

You really do not need to make things complicated when they are simple !

All you need is this :

```
if (first_date > second_date) 
    return True
else
    return False
```

Or in your case:

```
def get_value_for_dates(row):
    if row['first_column'] > row['second_column']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['value'] = df.apply(get_value_for_dates, axis=1)
```